# SFSE UI favourite question icon issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Looks like favorite icon bit cut out from down side

Please see below images or this should be like this only

[image]

[image]

---

Updates

As [@sandwich](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/users/13639/sandwich) mentioned Another issue

> also note that the post score is way too low between the arrows, as
>   your screenshot shows.

Comment: good catch Ratan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed now, it will be live after our next production build.

Comment: looks like this issue fixed now. Did you get a chance to look at 2nd bug mentioned by [sandwich](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/13639/sandwich) i.e. **also note that the post score is way too low between the arrows,** or this is just ok ?

Comment: @Ratan I pushed a fix for it, it'll be live in the next build :).

Comment: Stéphane.. Thank you. :-)